# Understanding addresses in C

Tags: c, pointers

For some structure `splab`:

```
int main() {

   int a;
   struct splab *s1;
   int b;

   printf("%x\n",&a);
   printf("%x\n",&b);

   return 0;
 }
```

I think I should get in the second print: `bfc251e8 - 8` (i.e. account for the space occupied by `s1`).

Instead, I got:

```
bfc251e8
bfc251ec
```

Why?

Comment: What is tha meaning of this bfc251e8-8=bfc251e8?

Comment: It's likely that the compiler has optimised `s1` away entirely, as you aren't using it.

Comment: and one thing Address is not fix it would be any address. we cant predict it would be sequential

Comment: Your question was a little unclear. I have edited it to be clearer, and removed the `=bfc251e8` part because it seemed confusing.

Answer (score 5):

It's not just really about the order of the variables. You never use `s1` and the compiler can (and *may*) simply optimize it away and not allocate space on the stack.

Here is what I get if I try to print only the addresses of `a` and `b`, like you do:

```
ffeb7448 (&a)
ffeb7444 (&b)
```

i.e. 4 bytes difference.

Here is what I get if I try to print the address of `s1` also (and therefore end up *using* the declaration `s1`):

```
ffe109cc (&a)
ffe109c8 (&s1)
ffe109c4 (&b)
```

You can see that it does in fact lie in between `a` and `b` this time (and it need not always, as other answers already point out), and that `a` and `b` are separated by 8 bytes instead of 4.

---

Another slightly related point has to do with alignment:

For example:

```
struct foo
{
  int a;
  char b;
};
```

While this struct looks like it might be 5 bytes wide on a machine with 4 byte integers, my compiler says, `sizeof (struct foo) == 8`.

This is so that `foo` is always aligned at 8 byte boundaries (this includes use of `struct foo` local variables).

e.g.

```
int bar (void)
{
  struct foo a;
  struct foo b;

  /* Do some work.  */
}
```

Here, `a` and `b` are separated by 8 bytes on my machine's compiler, even though each `foo` only really ever uses 5 bytes.

All this goes to show is: *Never* assume anything related to widths, alignment, relative position, etc. when writing code.

Comment: thank you. why is important what is splab? s is just a pointer-4 bytes. no?

Comment: @user1462787 - You are right. No it is not important. I just declared it to because I figured the compiler will warn me when it sees that `splab` is undeclared. I see now that it does not do so.

Comment: @user1462787 - By the way, off-topic and to remember in the future - Don't always expect pointers and integers to be 4 bytes wide. Widths are machine dependent.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is free to reorder the location of the variables on the stack, so it is possible that the `b` variable comes before the `s1` pointer, although the latter is declared in the middle.

Such rearrangements might enable better memory utilisation due to some data types requiring alignment, therefore eliminating any possible gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying because the pointer `s1` was allocated between `a` and `b` the addresses needed to vary by the amount the pointer uses memory? (It wasn't quite clear to me).

If so, I don't think you can count on this, how memory is allocated between different variables is not under your control. It may appear that memory is allocated in a linear fashion, but it's not something that you can rely on.

If I'm wrong interpreting your question/could you please rephrase/clarify it?

Comment: moreover even if you could rely on that, the compiler is allowed to rearrange the order of your variable declarations. see the assembly that is generated, with different `-O` values

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter yes, good point further showing that we ought not to make any assumption about how different variables get mapped into memory space

Comment: When I define in c:

     int i;
     int j;

Which address is bigger? 

    &i or &j ?  

Are they always in the stack?